# Does Unreal Engine Has Good grapic texture editor or I have to Learn Maya?

Tags: udk, unreal

I'm new in game Development , and I had no experience of it (except programming)
So , for my Engine , I preferred to use Unreal Engine. So here's the question:
Are Maya or 3D'sMax needed to be learned or Unreal Engine has a built in Editor ?
and , in comment , After i learned graphic , witch programming Language Does Unreal Engine support and recommended ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unreal Engine does not provide a builtin editor for creating graphical content like meshes and textures. Even if it did you would probably better off using a tool that is dedicated to the job because UE is doing a lot more and totally different things for you.

For the programming language you will use C++ for traditional coding but can also use a visual programming language called Blueprint. You can use one of the two without the other or mix it up as they are designed to interact with each other. You can start reading in the wiki from here: [Programming Guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/index.html)